# Change Chart control Axis color?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

Please take a look at this:

[image]

Can i modify the default black color of the Axis ?
I have searched for this and changed several properties but it is still black.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried this, Chart would be your chart object you have created

```
//0 would be indice of chart area you wish to Change, Color.ColorYouWant
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Red;
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Red;

//To change the Colors of the interlacing lines you access them like so
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.InterlacedColor = Color.Red;
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.InterlacedColor = Color.Red;

//If you are looking to change the color of the Grid Lines
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Second line should be: Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Red; and not Chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Red;